# PHP: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, insert

Me genera este error, en mi codigo, y no se que quiere decir, ya lo revice demasiado, y no se que fallo. Porfavor ayudenme, apensa estoy aprendiendo php y mysql,.. muchas gracias!
esta es la pagina, que me genera el problema.

```
<form action="adddat.php" method="post">
 <div>
   <p>Nombre Cliente</p>
      <input type="text" name="nomcliente" id="nomcliente" placeholder="Nombre" required="required" class="validate[required] agenda-input">
   </div>
<p><label>Fecha de Pedido:</label><br>
    <input type="date" id="fecped" name="fecpedd"></p>
    <p><label>Fecha de Entrega:</label><br>
    <input type="date" id="fecent " name="fecentt"></p>           
    <p><label for="pr">Genero</label></p>
    <select name="pro">
    <?php
     include("cn.php");
      $sql="SELECT * FROM genero ORDER BY nomgen";
      $respro=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die (":p");
      while($rowpro = mysqli_fetch_array($respro)) {
      printf("<option value=%s>%s</option>",
      $rowpro["cod"],$rowpro["nomgen"]);
       } mysqli_free_result($respro);
      ?>
        </select>
      <p>Libros</p>
      <select id="ciu" name="ciu" class="agenda-input">
      <?php
      include("cn.php");
      $sql="SELECT * FROM libro ORDER BY nomlib";
       $resciu=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die (":p");
        while($rowciu = mysqli_fetch_array($resciu)) {
         printf("<option value=%s>%s</option>",
          $rowciu["cod"],$rowciu["nomlib"]);
           }mysqli_free_result($resciu);
            ?>
          </select>
       
          <p><div class="submit"></p>
            <input type="submit" name="button-blue" value="Guardar" id="button-blue"/>
            <div class="ease"></div>
```

el select si me muestra los datos, pero no los guarda.. si, de igual manera me pueden ayudar en eso jiji

```
adddat.php
<?php
include("cn.php");
$sql="INSERT INTO alquiler VALUES (NULL,'".$_POST["nomcliente"]."','".$_POST["fecpedd"]."','".$_POST["fecentt"]."'
    '".$_POST["pro"]."','".$_POST["ciu"]."')";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ("Problemas al insertar".mysqli_error($con));
header("location: exito.php");
?>
```

Comment: Saludos. Te sugiero especificar las columnas de la tabla y quitar (mientras pruebas) la instrucción `header(...);`. Igual veo que tienes 2 `POST` que inician con `fec` observa que estes allí pasando el formato que acepta mysql (si mal no recuerdo es *año-mes-dia*); así mismo (salvo error al copiar-pegar) entre el `fecentt` y `pro` hace falta una coma.

Answer (score 0):

El error *`Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`* ocurre generalmente cuando en una consulta SQL del tipo `INSERT` **el número de `VALUES` no coincide con la cantidad de columnas de la tabla**.

Actualmente estás pasando 6 valores para ser insertados en tu tabla `alquiler`, pero es probable que esa tabla tenga más (o menos) de 6 columnas.

Debes por tanto verificar cuántas columnas tiene esa tabla realmente.

En ese mismo tenor, te recomendaría **evitar consultas del tipo `INSERT` con columnas implícitas** (no escribir los nombres de columnas). Esto dificulta el análisis del código, difunde un estilo de programación perezoso, provoca errores como el actual y podría romper aplicaciones grandes en las que se use constantemente este tipo de programación y alguna tabla evolucione (agregando o quitando alguna columna).

Otra cosa, para hacer el código menos confuso, puedes **evitar tantas concatenaciones con el punto**. En cadenas rodeadas por comillas dobles, puedes suprimir las comillas de las claves del `$_POST` (que es un array) y dejar una sola cadena.

Tu consulta podría quedar así por ejemplo (aplicando nombre explícito de columnas y lo dicho sobre la concatenación):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO alquiler 
      (
        cUno, 
        cDos,
        cTres,
        cCuatro,
        cCinco,
        cSeis
       ) 
      VALUES
      ( 
        NULL,
        '$_POST[nomcliente]',
        '$_POST[fecpedd]',
        '$_POST[fecentt]',
        '$_POST[pro]',
        '$_POST[ciu]'
       )";
```

En la consulta se han puesto explícitamente los nombres de cada columna (`cUno`, `cDos`, etc) y se han puesto las claves del `$_POST` sin comillas, por ejemplo, para `$_POST[nomcliente]` no se ha puesto comillas alrededor de `nomcliente`, lo cual es totalmente válido en este caso, permitiendo un código más claro.

También se ha *identado* la consulta, de forma que se pueda ver fácilmente cuántas columnas y cuantos valores hay. La claridad en el código también es importante. No es lo mismo leer o analizar un código todo junto que un código debidamente organizado e identado.

### PD

Habría otras recomendaciones como usar **consultas preparadas**, pero has dicho en la pregunta que apenas empiezas y prefiero no liarte ahora con eso. Tampoco es el tema de esta pregunta.